# How to change Python Version in Terminal? (MacOS)

Tags: python, bash, interpreter

when I type
`type python3` it shows `python3 is /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3`

I'm trying to change it so that it shows `python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3`

This is currently what pulls up when I type `nano .bash_profile` in the terminal:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
Export PATH


>>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
```

I have two other anaconda python interpreters that I don't wish to use. Please help.

Comment: Could I see your `PATH` env?

Comment: I am using `venv` on a regular basis while working on `macOS` - the best solution so far, when it comes to dealing with multiple `PYTHON` releases.

Comment: @AnhPC03 How could I find that?

Comment: @AnhPC03 Is this what you're needing?

echo $PATH
/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this to prevent conda auto initialize base environment when open terminal

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

And change `false` to `true` to activate auto initialize conda environment